# Python Code Exiting Before Producing Output/Is there a Limit on the Size of Soup Objects?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some code that uses beautiful soup to parse very large (>100mb, some up to 500mb) xml files. I am not a professional programmer, I just use programming tools for research, so I apologize for any stupid questions.

**EDIT** The below code creates the same error, but is far more succint

```
import os
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import re

directory_in_str = 'some directory'

directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)


for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    full_name = directory_in_str + filename
    handler = open(full_name).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, 'html.parser')


with io.open('somecsv.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #Write header
        f.writelines(soup)
```

It is supposed to create a soup object of the whole file and then iterate through it to identify certain elements

I am not sure whether it is a limit on the size of a soup object, but whenever I run the code, I am getting the "===RESTART: Shell===" line in IDLE, without any output. Like this:

```
 RESTART: directory\nameofprogram.py 

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>>
```

If I run it from command line, it just exits before producing an output.

I am wondering if the object itself is too large to be stored as a soup object, so it is just killing the program (no error is produced, it just restarts). The code works fine on smaller files, and I was able to do a similar operation (storing the whole file in soup and then iterating through it) with txt files (formatted as xml, but stored as txt) that were up to 180+ MB, and the current code seems to be failing for files right around that size.

Is there a limit for the size of soup objects? Is it different for different file types? Would converting all of the xml files to txt files solve anything?

I have heard of ElementTree and iterparse, but I am not sure how I would convert something like the above into code that uses those tools. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please provide some code that reproduces the issue in fewer than 350 lines.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I just added one

Comment: Since there's not a lot to go on this issue without experiencing the same thing.John beautifulsoup is considered a slow way of parsing HTML, especially with XML (html.parser is faster but try others). I haven't encountered anything like this since I didn't work with 180mb+. 
One thing to also note is that you have a lot of try, except blocks. Since you've used them I'm guessing you know how they work. That's why you  only use except on certain exceptions (I'm not blaming since I do the same) but for debugging it will be needed that you remove them and only catch the ones that you expect.

Comment: In the simplified example you posted, I believe you should indent the portion where you're writing to a file. Otherwise you'll discard everything except the last file in the directory.